# CSS: Removing borders around images screws up image positioning

Tags: css, image, xhtml, margin, border

I'm trying to put a list of images horizontally into a wide, short bar. When I originally positioned the images, there were borders around each. But when I removed the borders, the images all shifted down a few pixels, so they no longer appear contained in the bar.

Oddly, after -1.1em (or -11px), the top margin of the images won't decrease any more. This is regardless of whether I have borders around the images or not; it's just that -1.1em is small enough with the borders but isn't without the borders.

My HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul class="images">
        <li><img src="1.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="2.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="3.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="4.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="5.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="6.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="7.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="8.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="long_image.bmp"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
div .wrap {
position: relative;
height: 2.5em;
line-height: 2.5em;
border: #000000 .1em solid;
}

ul .images {
list-style-type: none;
}

li {
display: inline;
}

li img {
margin-top: -1.1em;
border-bottom: #000000 .1em solid;
}
```

Comment: not part of the problem, but avoid using .bmp images on the web.

Comment: Thanks, I know, but this won't be hitting the web for a long time and I want to keep my images in an easily editable state.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul id="list_images">
        <li><img src="1.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="2.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="3.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="4.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="5.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="6.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="7.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="8.bmp"/></li>
        <li><img src="long_image.bmp"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#list_images ul{
  margin: 18px 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#list_images ul li{
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#list_images ul li img{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, it made my images enormous/fuzzy and not contained in the bar at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving 
`li {
display: block;
float: left;
list-style: none;
}`